# GLFW Can't compile example netbeans mingw w64

Tags: c++, netbeans, compiler-errors, glfw, mingw-w64

I used the precompiled version of GLFW for windows. I use netbeans and i can't resolve this error.

```
    "/E/Develop/Util/msys/bin/make.exe" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
    make.exe[1]: Entering directory `/e/Develop/Project/Netbeans/C++/CppApplication_1'
    "/E/Develop/Util/msys/bin/make.exe"  -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk dist/Debug/MinGW-w64_x64_-posix-seh-Windows/cppapplication_1.exe
    make.exe[2]: Entering directory `/e/Develop/Project/Netbeans/C++/CppApplication_1'
    mkdir -p build/Debug/MinGW-w64_x64_-posix-seh-Windows
    rm -f "build/Debug/MinGW-w64_x64_-posix-seh-Windows/main.o.d"
    g++    -c -g -I/E/Develop/Library/C++/GLFW\ 3.0.4/include -MMD -MP -MF "build/Debug/MinGW-w64_x64_-posix-seh-Windows/main.o.d" -o build/Debug/MinGW-w64_x64_-posix-seh-Windows/main.o main.cpp
    mkdir -p dist/Debug/MinGW-w64_x64_-posix-seh-Windows
    g++     -o dist/Debug/MinGW-w64_x64_-posix-seh-Windows/cppapplication_1 build/Debug/MinGW-w64_x64_-posix-seh-Windows/main.o -L../../../../Library/C++/GLFW\ 3.0.4/lib-mingw -L../../../../Compiler/C++/MinGW-w64\(x64\)-posix-seh/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib -lglfw3 -lglfw3dll
    e:/Develop/Compiler/C++/MinGW-w64(x64)-posix-seh/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lglfw3dll
    collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
    make.exe[2]: *** [dist/Debug/MinGW-w64_x64_-posix-seh-Windows/cppapplication_1.exe] Error 1
    make.exe[2]: Leaving directory `/e/Develop/Project/Netbeans/C++/CppApplication_1'
    make.exe[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
    make.exe[1]: Leaving directory `/e/Develop/Project/Netbeans/C++/CppApplication_1' make.exe": *** [.build-impl] Error 2
```

i add the directory and linked the Libraries like [this](http://s14.postimg.org/kbx6nrvld/Immagine.png)

[this is the code](http://pastebin.com/p0UskQza)

how can i fix this?

Comment: "-L../../../../Library/C++/GLFW\ 3.0.4/lib-mingw" - extra space after the backslash looks suspicious

Comment: @HEKTO relative path, same problem with absolute path

Comment: I think the g++ doesn't like paths with spaces embedded. Can you reinstall the GLFW without this "GLFW 3.0.4" dirname? Like "GLFW_3.0.4" or similar?

Comment: I think I got it... the GLFW has two versions of libraries - static and dynamic (DLL). If you want to link with the static library, then you don't have to include the "glfw3dll" into the list of libraries. See the "Building programs that use GLFW" section of your doc for more info. They also mention other libraries you need to link to

Comment: @HEKTO yup resolved but now give me another error

Comment: Great, I'm copying that into the answer area...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The GLFW has two versions of libraries - static and dynamic (DLL). If you want to link with the static library, then you won't have to include the `glfw3dll` (which is a DLL *link* library) into the list of libraries. Please see the [Building programs that use GLFW](http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/build.html) for more info. They also mention other libraries you need to link to.